# CUDA resample from non-even sampling

Tags: c++, cuda, interpolation, tex

I'd like to resample (interpolate) a sequence from a non-uniformed samplings. I don't think tex works because it basically does interpolation assuming your sample is uniform? Doing search would be too slow?

Should I do thrust? Any pointer is appreciated it. Any examples would be greatly helpful.

**UPDATE:**

Say the line with circle mark is my sample. I know the value at each circle point. Obviously, the sample is evenly distributed on the horizontal axis.

Now, I would like to know the value at each x mark on the line underneath the sampling line. The x mark are uniformly distributed along the line.

---o--------o----o------o------o------o------       (sampling)

--X-----X-----X-----X-----X-----X-----X---          (known to interpolate)

So I am wondering how to get the values at each x mark position using CUDA? Obviously, the most basic algorithm using C/C++ would be for each x mark position, search for the two nearest circle position, then do linear interpolation. But in this case, you need to first sort two sequence, then loop over x mark, and for each x mark, you do the search. This just sounds expansive.

I am wondering how we should do it in CUDA? Thanks.

Comment: The question seems vaguely and overly broad. A minimal example code and sample data that demonstrates what kind of processing you intend to do would clarify and narrow down the question.

Comment: @njuffa Hi I did a little update, does that help? Thanks.

Comment: Not really. It would be better if you could  show the (non-CUDA) code you are currently using to do the interpolation. What kind of interpolation is being used? Linear, quadratic, cubic spline, etc ?

Comment: @njuffa: I am discussing a general idea here. What kind of interpolation is just a detailed question. They all do the work, and difference is minor if you have a good enough sampling, which normally you do in reality. Let's say we start from linear, and the algorithm is simple in CPU code, C/C++, like I described in the update. The point is how to design and implement (what tool to use for example) it in CUDA. I am hoping someone who has experience with it could give me some pointer.

Comment: I think its going to be "expensive".  It's not clear to me why you have to do sorting. Are your known samples (`o`) *not* sorted?  That seems odd, but in that case you would have to sort 1 sequence, not 2.  Then you have a bunch of binary searches to do.  With CUDA you can do the sorting and the searching in parallel.  Once you've found the appropriate point, the 2-nearest-neighbor interpolation is simple.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: You are absolutely right. Normally samples are sorted based on time or position. I am just extending it to a more difficult situation. Because as long as the points and their positions are given, it is a deterministic problem. Sorted or not, it should have only one answer. For now, it is OK to assume the sequence is sorted.

Comment: Actually, I would like to come back to the question raised by @njuffa.  Your question seems to suggest that you are willing to interpolate based on the nearest neighbor to the left, and the nearest neighbor to the right (i.e. linear interpolation).  Is that correct?  Or do you need multiple neighbors (e.g for cubic spline)?  This is not just a detail question, it affects algorithm choice, in my opinion.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I agree with  you. In my answer to njuffa, I said "Let's say we start from linear". I have not found a solution how to do cubic spline in CUDA yet. I think I can only do it in C/C++ for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a number of approaches.  For example you could use a basic [cuda binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658518/search-an-ordered-array-in-a-cuda-kernel) in a thread-parallel fashion.  I'll demonstrate a [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) implementation.

For the purpose of this discussion, I'll assume that both data sets (known sample points, and desired sample points) are arbitrarily placed (i.e. I'm not assuming either sample set is evenly spaced).  However I will stipulate or require that the desired sample points are *fully contained* within the known sample points.   I believe this is sensible as usual linear interpolation requires a known sample point on either side of the desired sample point.

Therefore we'll use a data set like this:

```
   o:  1,3,7
f(o):  3,7,15
   x:  1.5, 2.5, 4.5, 5.0, 6.0, 6.5
f(x):    ?,   ?,   ?,   ?,   ?,   ?
```

We see that `f` is the known functional values, that correspond to `f(o) = 2o+1`, a straight line in this case (although this method does not require the known sample points to fit any particular function).  `x` represent the indices at which we desire to interpolate the functional value, based on the known values (`f(o)`).  Our desire then is to compute `f(x)` via interpolation from the nearest `f(o)` points.  Note that our data set is such that all values of `x` lie between the minimum (1)  and maximum (7) `o` values.  This is the stipulation/requirement I stated earlier.

Our thrust method will be to use a vectorized binary search, using `thrust::upper_bound`, to locate the "insertion point" where each desired `x` value fits within the `o` sequence.  This gives us our right neighbor, and left neighbor (right-1) for interpolation.  Once we know the insertion point, it would be a trivial extension of this algorithm to choose e.g. the *two* left and *two* right neighbors (or more) if we wanted to use something other than linear interpolation.

The insertion point then gives us our left and right neighbors, and we use this information to pass to an appropriately crafted `thrust::transform` operation the `x` vector (desired interpolation points) along with a `thrust::tuple` (via `thrust::zip_iterator`) that provides:

- the right neighbor index
- the right neighbor functional value
- the left neighbor index
- the left neighbor functional value

With these quantities, plus the desired index (`x`), interpolation is straightforward.

**EDIT:** Inspired by the other answer, I decided to include a method that avoids a parallel binary search, but instead uses a prefix-sum method to identify the insertion indices for the `x` data in the `o` data.  This method assumes *both* `x` and `o` sequences are sorted.

We will start with a merge_by_key operation.  We will merge `x` with `o`, to establish the ordering (this seems more efficient than binary search).  The `x` and `o` quantities will be the "keys" and the values will be all 1 for `o` and all 0 for `x`.  Using our sample data then, the merge_by_key will produce this:

```
o keys:  1,3,7
o vals:  1,1,1

x keys:  1.5,2.5,4.5,5.0,6.0,6.5
x vals:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0

merged keys:  1, 1.5, 2.5,   3, 4.5, 5.0, 6.0, 6.5,   7
merged vals:  1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1
```

When we do a prefix sum (inclusive scan) on the merged vals we get:

```
ins. ind.:    1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   3
```

We can then do a copy_if operation to extract just the insertion indices associated with the `x` vals (whose merged vals are zero) to produce the same insertion index sequence produced in step 1:

```
 d_i:  1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

The remainder of method 2 can then use exactly the same remaining interpolation code (`thrust::transform`) as was used in method 1.

Here's a fully worked example showing both methods:

```
$ cat t1224.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/merge.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>

struct interp_func
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(float t1, T t2){  // m = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)  y = m(x-x0) + y0
    return ((thrust::get<1>(t2) - thrust::get<3>(t2))/(thrust::get<0>(t2) - thrust::get<2>(t2)))*(t1 - thrust::get<2>(t2)) + thrust::get<3>(t2);
    }
};

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  // sample data
  float o[] = {1.0f, 3.0f, 7.0f}; // unevenly spaced sample points for function f
  float f[] = {3.0f, 7.0f, 15.0f}; // f(o) = 2o+1
  float x[] = {1.5f, 2.5f, 4.5f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 6.5f}; // additional desired sample points for f
  int so = sizeof(o)/sizeof(o[0]);
  int sx = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);

  // setup data on device
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_o(o, o+so);
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_f(f, f+so);
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_x(x, x+sx);
  thrust::device_vector<int>   d_i(sx); // insertion indices
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_r(sx); // results
  // method 1: binary search
  // perform search for insertion indices
  thrust::upper_bound(d_o.begin(), d_o.end(), d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), d_i.begin());
  // then perform linear interpolation based on left and right neighbors
  std::cout << "Method 1 insertion indices:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_i.begin(), d_i.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::transform(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_o.begin(), d_i.begin()), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_f.begin(), d_i.begin()), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_o.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_i.begin(), _1-1)), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_f.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_i.begin(), _1-1)))), d_r.begin(), interp_func());

  // output results
  std::cout << "Interpolation points:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "Interpolated values:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_r.begin(), d_r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "Expected values:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < sx; i++) std::cout << 2*x[i]+1 <<  ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  //method 2: merge + prefix sum
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_kr(sx+so);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_vr(sx+so);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_s(sx+so);
  thrust::merge_by_key(d_o.begin(), d_o.end(), d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), thrust::constant_iterator<int>(1), thrust::constant_iterator<int>(0), d_kr.begin(), d_vr.begin());
  thrust::inclusive_scan(d_vr.begin(), d_vr.end(), d_s.begin());
  thrust::copy_if(d_s.begin(), d_s.end(), d_vr.begin(), d_i.begin(), _1 == 0);
  std::cout << "Method 2 insertion indices:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_i.begin(), d_i.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  // remainder of solution method would be identical to end of method 1 starting with the thrust::transform
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1224 t1224.cu
$ ./t1224
Method 1 insertion indices:
1,1,2,2,2,2,
Interpolation points:
1.5,2.5,4.5,5,6,6.5,
Interpolated values:
4,6,10,11,13,14,
Expected values:
4,6,10,11,13,14,
Method 2 insertion indices:
1,1,2,2,2,2,
$
```

Again, once we know the insertion point, choosing 2 right and 2 left neighbors for more involved interpolation would be a trivial extension.  We would just modify the zip iterator being passed to the transform (interpolation) functor, and modify the functor itself to implement the desired arithmetic.

Also note that this method assumes the input `o` sequence is already sorted.  If it is not, then it would be necessary to add a sort-by-key of `o` (keys) with `f` (values).  The `x` sequence need not be sorted for method 1, but must be sorted for method 2 (merging requires that both sequences are sorted).

Comment: Robert, I try to use vs 2012 build your code, it says "_1" is undefined. In the thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_i.begin(), _1-1)); Any idea? I am using cuda 6.5.

Comment: Do  you have the `using namespace thrust::placeholders;` in your file as I do?   What CUDA version are you using?  What gpu target architecture are you compiling for?

Answer (score 3):

The details of the best approach depend on the sizes involved (i.e. is it a large batch of short sequences or a single gigantic sequence, etc.), but at a high level you can do this with only a (parallel potentially O(N)) sort of the input sequence and a parallel prefix sum. In particular you can avoid any binary searching. Check out the ideas behind "intervalExpand" of modernGPU: https://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/intervalmove.html

Briefly in pseudo-code:

```
1:  sort the input sequence
2:  for each input point seq[i]: 
      let count[i] = number of output points in the interval [seq[i], seq[i+1])
3:  let indices = exclusive prefix-sum of count
4:  use intervalExpand() to go from seq, count, indices to the desired output.
```

You can stick in whatever interpolation formula you want in step 4, including linear, cubic etc.  The important thing is that intervalExpand will tell you for each *output* index, which are the correct *input* indices that sandwich the output.

Again, if you are working with a large batch of smallish sequences, binary search may actually be faster to run and easier to write.  Otherwise you should be able to use the templatized code in the modernGPU library to do this relatively painlessly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this is probably a better approach than my answer.  I was thinking of various approaches using prefix sums, but hadn't settled on this.

Comment: Thanks Always Confused!