# Equivalent of 1D numpy.interp in C++ Cuda (Lerp in CUDA)

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cuda, lerp

I have two vectors 'xp' and 'fp' which correspond to the x and y values respectively of the data. A third vector 'x' which is the x coordinates at which I would like to evaluate the interpolated values. My results in python using NumPy's interp function was as expected.

```
import numpy as np 

xp = np.array([1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 14.0, 17.0, 18.0, 20.0])
yp = xp**2
x = np.array([3,5])
np.interp(x,xp,yp) #array([  9.25,  26.  ])
```

My question is how do I replicate this algorithm inside a cuda kernel?

Here is my attempt:

size --> len(xp) == len(fp),
x_size --> len(x).

```
__global__ void lerp_kernel(double* xp, double* yp, double* output_result, 
                          double* x, unsigned int size, unsigned int x_size)
{
  for( unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ; idx < size ; idx += 
  blockDim.x*gridDim.x )

{     
 
 if(idx > size - 2){    
  idx = size - 2; 
  }
  double dx = xp[idx + 1] - xp[idx];
  double dy = yp[idx + 1] - yp[idx];
  double dydx = dy/dx ;
  double lerp_result = yp[idx] + (dydx * (x[idx] - xp[idx]));
  output_result[idx] = lerp_result;
  
   }
  }
```

I think one of the mistakes I am making is that I am not searching for the index range in xp that contains x (using something like numpy.searchsorted in python). I am not sure how to implement this part in CUDA. If someone knows a better way to do lerp in cuda, please let me know.

I have seen lerp functions in the documentation of Cg (https://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/lerp.html), but these need a weight vector (fraction between 0-1) for the x vector. I am not sure how to rescale x so that I can use a weight vector to solve this problem.

Comment: there's [a whole blog article](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/lerp-faster-cuda/) on it.  and the lerp link you have provided is **not CUDA**, it is Cg.

Comment: Oops you are right, it is Cg. Will update the post accordingly. I have seen that blog article before. If I understood it correctly, t needs to be a number between 0 and 1. How do I transform my x vector into that? Should I rescale 'x' using min(xp) and max(fp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mimic the behavior of `numpy.interp` will require several steps.  We'll make at least one simplifying assumption: the `numpy.interp` function [expects](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) your `xp` array to be increasing (we could probably also say "sorted").  Otherwise it specifically mentions a need to do an (internal) sorting.  We'll skip that case and assume that your `xp` array is increasing, as you have shown here.

The numpy function also allows the `x` array to be more-or-less arbitrary, from what I can see.

In order to do a proper interpolation, we must find the "segment" of `xp` that each `x` value belongs to.  The only way I can think of is to perform a [binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658518/search-an-ordered-array-in-a-cuda-kernel/21660779#21660779).  (also note that [thrust](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__binary__search.html) has convenient binary searches)

The process then would be:

1. using a binary search per element in `x`, find the corresponding "segment" (i.e. endpoints) in `xp`
2. use the equation of a line (y=mx+b), based on the identified segment, to compute the interpolated value between the endpoints

Here's an example:

```
$ cat t40.cu
#include <iostream>

typedef int lt;

template <typename T>
__device__ void bsearch_range(const T *a, const T key, const lt len_a, lt *idx){
  lt lower = 0;
  lt upper = len_a;
  lt midpt;
  while (lower < upper){
    midpt = (lower + upper)>>1;
    if (a[midpt] < key) lower = midpt +1;
    else upper = midpt;
    }
  *idx = lower;
  return;
  }


template <typename T>
__global__ void my_interp(const T *xp, const T *yp, const lt xp_len, const lt x_len, const T *x, T *y){

  for (lt i = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x; i < x_len; i+=gridDim.x*blockDim.x){
    T val = x[i];
    if ((val >= xp[0]) && (val < xp[xp_len - 1])){
      lt idx;
      bsearch_range(xp, val, xp_len, &idx);
      T xlv = xp[idx-1];
      T xrv = xp[idx];
      T ylv = yp[idx-1];
      T yrv = yp[idx];
     // y  =      m                *   x       + b
      y[i] = ((yrv-ylv)/(xrv-xlv)) * (val-xlv) + ylv;
    }
  }
}

typedef float mt;
const int nTPB = 256;
int main(){

  mt xp[] = {1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 14.0, 17.0, 18.0, 20.0};
  lt xp_len = sizeof(xp)/sizeof(xp[0]);
  mt *yp = new mt[xp_len];
  for (lt i = 0; i < xp_len; i++) yp[i] = xp[i]*xp[i];
  mt x[] = {3,5};
  lt x_len = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
  mt *y = new mt[x_len];
  mt *d_xp, *d_x, *d_yp, *d_y;
  cudaMalloc(&d_xp, xp_len*sizeof(xp[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&d_yp, xp_len*sizeof(yp[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&d_x,   x_len*sizeof( x[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&d_y,   x_len*sizeof( y[0]));
  cudaMemcpy(d_xp, xp, xp_len*sizeof(xp[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_yp, yp, xp_len*sizeof(yp[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, x_len*sizeof(x[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  my_interp<<<(x_len+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(d_xp, d_yp, xp_len, x_len, d_x, d_y);
  cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, x_len*sizeof(y[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (lt i = 0; i < x_len; i++) std::cout << y[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t40 t40.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t40
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
9.25,26,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I'm not suggesting the above code is defect-free or suitable for any particular purpose.  My objective here is to demonstrate a method, not offer a fully tested code.  In particular, edge cases probably need to be tested carefully (values at the edge of the overall range, or outside the range, for example).