# CuPy parallel searchsorted

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, cupy

The current `searchsorted` works perfect with 1-d arrays:

```
import cupy as cp
ref = cp.arange(5, dtype=cp.float32)
secs = cp.arange(10, dtype=cp.float32)
cp.searchsorted(ref,secs)
```

the result is:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

I want a function `multi_searchsorted` that search each row of `ref` in parallel, for example:

For `ref`:

```
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]], dtype=float32)
```

and `secs`:

```
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]], dtype=float32)
```

It will produce

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Does anybody know if there is any open source code implement it? If I have to write the code, do I need to rewrite the kernel from beginning or if I can reuse the existing `searchsorted` function in some way?

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: The easiest solution might be to just asynchronously do multiple calls to `searchsorted` on multiple CUDA streams. There is probably not much to gain from doing it in a single launch.

Comment: In my opinion, the gains from a single launch could be significant if the row width is small, say, less than 10,000 elements, and especially if there are a large number of "small" rows.  In that case, I would either [write my own segmented binary search kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658518/search-an-ordered-array-in-a-cuda-kernel), which should be doable in cupy RawKernel, or else (better) use a vectorized search from thrust.  I still wonder if there is a clever way to do the segmented search using cupy searchsorted, however.  Perhaps if the domain is limited, with offsets.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588403/vectorized-searchsorted-numpy) may be of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @paleonix @robert-crovella. I find pytorch implement n-dimensional `searchsorted`. Since there is no cost to convert data between pytorch and cupy, this should be the simplest way. But the speed needs to be test. I will test the speed of pytorch `searchsorted` and a clever version of cupy `searchsorted`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytorch have a nD `searchsorted` and there is a smart way to convert nD problem to 1D as @robert-crovella mentioned. I write two version of functions to test their speed:

```
import cupy as cp
import torch
from cupyx.profiler import benchmark
```

The first one is basically a simple wrapper around pytorch `searchsorted`:

```
def torch_searchsorted(ref,sec)
    _ref = torch.as_tensor(ref)
    _sec = torch.as_tensor(sec)
    indices = torch.searchsorted(_ref,_sec,side='right')
    indices = cp.asarray(indices)
    return indices
```

The second is the smart way:

```
def cupy_searchsorted(a,b):
    m,n = a.shape
    max_num = cp.maximum(a.max() - a.min(), b.max() - b.min()) + 1
    r = max_num*cp.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
    p = cp.searchsorted( (a+r).ravel(), (b+r).ravel(), side='right' ).reshape(m,-1)
    return p - n*(cp.arange(m)[:,None])
```

First test the correctness:

```
ref = cp.arange(20, dtype=cp.float32).reshape(4,5)
sec = cp.arange(-1,19, dtype=cp.float32).reshape(4,5)
torch_out = torch_searchsorted(ref,sec)
cupy_out = cupy_searchsorted(ref,sec)
```

The results are same:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Then test the speed:

```
width = 100
nlines = 10000
ref = cp.arange(-1.1,-1.1+width*nlines, dtype=cp.float32).reshape(nlines,width)
sec = cp.arange(-1.5,-1.5+width*nlines, dtype=cp.float32).reshape(nlines,width)
print(benchmark(torch_searchsorted,(ref, sec), n_repeat=100))
print(benchmark(cupy_searchsorted,(ref, sec), n_repeat=100))
```

The result is much suprising:

```
torch_searchsorted  :    CPU: 8305.727 us   +/-737.419 (min: 8109.499 / max:15409.231) us     GPU-0: 8937.603 us   +/-737.363 (min: 8741.632 / max:16042.624) us
cupy_searchsorted   :    CPU:  354.953 us   +/- 9.935 (min:  346.325 / max:  429.802) us     GPU-0:  378.429 us   +/- 9.438 (min:  370.688 / max:  450.560) us
```

The cupy version is much faster.
I wonder if the data conversion costs too much time, so I do further test:

```
_ref = torch.as_tensor(ref)
_sec = torch.as_tensor(sec)
print(benchmark(torch.searchsorted,(_ref, _sec), n_repeat=100))
```

I get

```
searchsorted        :    CPU: 5669.537 us   +/-86.444 (min: 5646.031 / max: 6487.139) us     GPU-0: 5677.324 us   +/-86.665 (min: 5653.792 / max: 6496.576) us
```

It gets faster but still not as fast as the cupy one.
The test is on V100. pytorch version is

`pytorch                   1.13.1          py3.9_cuda11.7_cudnn8.5.0_0    pytorch`

cupy version is 11.2.

Conclusion:

- Even pytorch `searchsorted` support nD, the performance is not so good.
- The data conversion between cupy and pytorch is not at no cost.